# Can UILocalizedIndexedCollation be changed without changing the device language?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, uilocalizedcollation

I'm using `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` to index the cells on a UITableView. The problem is that my app has a language system that is independent from the device. For example, the app language can be Chinese while the device is still in English.

**Is there a way to change `[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation]` without changing the device settings?**

Comment: Meet same problem, any one know this? I tried the "AppLanguage" way to change runtime locale, everything works except UILocalizedIndexedCollation, after restart app I got right result.

Comment: Still no solution to this issue that is sad..