# UILocalizedIndexedCollation with a different locale

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalizedcollation

I know this is a long shot but does anyone know if its possible to use UILocalizedIndexedCollation with a locale thats not the device locale?

i.e. a phone set to Chinese wants to view my app in english - oddly this is a real (and common) request from our users!)

Comment: Similar question (without answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965437/can-uilocalizedindexedcollation-be-changed-without-changing-the-device-language.

Comment: Whoops, that's not similar, it's exactly the same :) I'd vote to close this question but neither of them have an answer yet